# Gemfire Configuration for two different Lan

Tags: gemfire

All my servers and clients have two ip addresses. For example, Server A has 138.88.88.12 (Subnet Mask :255.255.255.0 - LAN A - Connect to Switch A)  and 138.88.89.13 (Subnet Mask :255.255.255.0 - LAN B - Connect to Switch B).

1. May i know what is the recommendation of Gemfire configuration for two LAN segment ?
2. May i know what ip address should i put for the bind address for Gemfire locators and servers?
3. Can i have network redundancy for my Gemfire servers and clients? For example, can the Gemfire still function properly if the LAN A or LAN B switch is down?

Gemfire Configuration

- 9.8.6 Version
- 2 Locators
- 3 Servers

Thank you so much for your help.